# return multiple items in array in method 2 and 3

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling with the method `printHighest` and `printLowest`, I need it to return the `student score`, `name` and `ID`, but I can't figure it out the only way that I was able to get it to work was only with the score, for the most part, the rest of the programs works just fine, I am just struggling with that part of the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FinalprojectV2
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] studentID = new int [5];
        String[] studentName = new String [5];
        int [] studentScore = new int [5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        { 
            System.out.println("Student Number " + (i+1) + "");

            System.out.println("Student ID Number: ");
            studentID [i] = console.nextInt();

            System.out.println(" Student Name: " + console.nextLine()+"");
            studentName [i] = console.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Grade: ");
            studentScore [i] = console.nextInt();
        }

        printRoaster(studentID, studentName, studentScore);

        int max = printLowest(studentScore);
        System.out.println("Highest score is: "+ max);

        int min = printHighest(studentScore);
        System.out.println("Lowest score is: "+ min);
    }

    public static void printRoaster(int[] studentID, String []studentName, int [] studentScore)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        { 
            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentID);
            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentName);
            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentScore);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(studentID[i] + " " + studentName [i] + " " + studentScore [i]  + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int printLowest(int[] inputArray)
    { 
        int maxValue = inputArray[0]; 

        for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){ 
            if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 
                maxValue = inputArray[i]; 
            }
        } 

        return maxValue; 
    }

    public static int printHighest(int[] inputArray){ 
        int minValue = inputArray[0];

        for(int i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){ 
            if(inputArray[i] < minValue){ 
                minValue = inputArray[i];
            }
        } 

        return minValue; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You could return instead the index of the max score then use it to retrieve the id and the name of the student with that score using that index.

Comment: can you provide a sample input and sample output

Comment: could you show me an example of how i would implement that into the code?

Answer (score 1):

Better solution would be - create a student class with id, name and score.

And from printHighest and printLowest methods, return appropriate objects of Student class.

Hope you understood.

```
class Student {
    int studentID;

    String studentName;

     int studentScore ;
........
}
```

In main method, create

```
Student[] students = new Student [5];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public class FinalprojectV2

{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] studentID = new int [5];

        String[] studentName = new String [5];

        int [] studentScore = new int [5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        {

            System.out.println("Student Number " + (i+1) + "");

            System.out.println("Student ID Number: ");

            studentID [i] = console.nextInt();

            System.out.println(" Student Name: " + console.nextLine()+"");

            studentName [i] = console.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Grade: ");

            studentScore [i] = console.nextInt();

        }

        printRoaster(studentID, studentName, studentScore);

//        int max = printLowest(studentScore);

        printLowest(studentScore,studentID);

//        System.out.println("Highest score is: "+ );

        int min = printHighest(studentScore);

        System.out.println("Lowest score is: "+ min);

    }

    public static void printRoaster(int[] studentID, String []studentName, int []

            studentScore)

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        {

            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentID);

            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentName);

            java.util.Arrays.sort(studentScore);

        }


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

        {

            System.out.println(studentID[i] + " " + studentName [i] + " " + studentScore [i]

                    + " ");

        }

    }

    public static void printLowest(int[] inputArray, int[] id)

    {
        int pos = MIN_VALUE;
        int maxValue = inputArray[0];

        for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){

            if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){

                pos = i;
                maxValue = inputArray[i];

            }

        }

        print(maxValue,id[pos]);

    }

    public static void print(int score, int id){
        System.out.println("Highest score is: "+ score +" student ID is: "+id);
    }

    public static int printHighest(int[] inputArray){

        int minValue = inputArray[0];

        for(int i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){

            if(inputArray[i] < minValue){

                minValue = inputArray[i];

            }

        }

        return minValue;

    }

}
```

I changed your code a little bit, so you will need to finish another method by yourself. Here i just separated method with print and added id array into calling printLowest mehod

Comment: This is the solution which introduce just a little changes in your code. The right and good practice is to write like @A J showed.